# Kafka issue WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error connecting to node.......java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to setup kafka in kubernetes. Everything starts fine including zookeeper and kafka-server as per their logs but when i try to produce message on a topic it says "Error connecting to node". Can anyone have a look at below yaml files and error and tell me what is the issue. Thanks.
Here are the details:

**zookeeper/deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-cluster1
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: zookeeper-cluster1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper-cluster1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: zookeeper-cluster1
        app: zookeeper-cluster1
    spec:
      hostname: zookeeper-cluster1
      containers:
        - name: zookeeper-cluster1
          image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2181
            - containerPort: 2888
            - containerPort: 3888
```

**zookeeper/service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-cluster1
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: zookeeper-cluster1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: zookeeper-cluster1
  ports:
    - name: zookeeper-cluster1
      protocol: TCP
      port: 2181
      targetPort: 2181
    - name: zookeeper-follower-cluster1
      protocol: TCP
      port: 2888
      targetPort: 2888
    - name: zookeeper-leader-cluster1
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3888
      targetPort: 3888
```

**kafka/deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kafka-cluster
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: kafka-cluster
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka-cluster
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: kafka-cluster
        app: kafka-cluster
    spec:
      hostname: kafka-cluster
      containers:
        - name: kafka-cluster
          image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
              value: PLAINTEXT://kafka-cluster:9092
            - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
              value: zookeeper-cluster1:2181
            - name: KAFKA_LISTENERS
              value: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9092
```

**kafka/service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-cluster
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: kafka-cluster
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: kafka-cluster
  ports:
    - name: kafka-cluster
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9092
      targetPort: 9092
```

**kafkacat output**

```
kafkacat -b 172.17.0.2:30511 -L

Metadata for all topics (from broker -1: 172.17.0.2:30511/bootstrap):
 1 brokers:
  broker 1001 at kafka-cluster:9092
 0 topics:
```

**error when message is produced**

```
    bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic admintome-test1 --bootstrap-server 172.17.0.2:30511
    >as
[2021-02-10 15:58:04,696] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error connecting to node kafka-cluster:9092 (id: 1001 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
java.net.UnknownHostException: kafka-cluster: Name or service not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1515)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.resolve(ClientUtils.java:110)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:403)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.access$200(ClusterConnectionStates.java:363)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:151)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:958)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.access$600(NetworkClient.java:74)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:1131)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:1019)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:542)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:325)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:240)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

**kafka-server logs**

```
[2021-02-10 10:50:01,044] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=1001] Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
[2021-02-10 10:50:01,091] INFO [Transaction Marker Channel Manager 1001]: Starting (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionMarkerChannelManager)
[2021-02-10 10:50:01,091] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=1001] Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
[2021-02-10 10:50:01,312] INFO Updated cache from existing <empty> to latest FinalizedFeaturesAndEpoch(features=Features{}, epoch=0). (kafka.server.FinalizedFeatureCache)
[2021-02-10 10:50:01,508] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1001-AlterAcls]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2021-02-10 10:50:01,641] INFO [/config/changes-event-process-thread]: Starting (kafka.common.ZkNodeChangeNotificationListener$ChangeEventProcessThread)
[2021-02-10 10:50:01,701] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1001] Starting socket server acceptors and processors (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2021-02-10 10:50:01,708] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1001] Started data-plane acceptor and processor(s) for endpoint : ListenerName(PLAINTEXT) (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2021-02-10 10:50:01,708] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1001] Started socket server acceptors and processors (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2021-02-10 10:50:01,716] INFO Kafka version: 2.7.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-02-10 10:50:01,716] INFO Kafka commitId: 448719dc99a19793 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-02-10 10:50:01,716] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1612954201709 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-02-10 10:50:01,718] INFO [KafkaServer id=1001] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-02-10 10:50:02,005] INFO [broker-1001-to-controller-send-thread]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use broker 1001 (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
```

**zookeeper logs**

```
2021-02-10 10:49:44,841 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ServerCnxnFactory@117] - Using org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory as server connection factory
2021-02-10 10:49:44,845 [myid:] - INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@89] - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
2021-02-10 10:49:59,583 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@215] - Accepted socket connection from /172.18.0.4:60322
2021-02-10 10:49:59,588 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@949] - Client attempting to establish new session at /172.18.0.4:60322
2021-02-10 10:49:59,590 [myid:] - INFO  [SyncThread:0:FileTxnLog@213] - Creating new log file: log.1
2021-02-10 10:49:59,601 [myid:] - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@694] - Established session 0x10007ad45a10000 with negotiated timeout 18000 for client /172.18.0.4:60322
2021-02-10 10:49:59,669 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@653] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10007ad45a10000 type:create cxid:0x2 zxid:0x3 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers
2021-02-10 10:49:59,679 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@653] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10007ad45a10000 type:create cxid:0x6 zxid:0x7 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /config
2021-02-10 10:49:59,686 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@653] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10007ad45a10000 type:create cxid:0x9 zxid:0xa txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/admin Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin
2021-02-10 10:49:59,948 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@653] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10007ad45a10000 type:create cxid:0x17 zxid:0x15 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/cluster Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /cluster
2021-02-10 10:50:01,804 [myid:] - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181)::PrepRequestProcessor@596] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10007ad45a10000 type:multi cxid:0x3e zxid:0x1e txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a aborting remaining multi ops. Error Path:/admin/preferred_replica_election Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/preferred_replica_election
```

Comment: My advice is, don't use something selfbuild. There are a lot of better options to run and maintain a kafka cluster in kubernetes. Take a look for strimzi kafka operator or confluent kafka operator. It saves you a lot of trouble.

Comment: BTW. How did you start the console producer? inside the cluster in the same namespace? Take a look for your KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS

Comment: Where did 30511 port come from? What is 172.17.0.2?

Comment: @ManuelPolacek I am trying to produce messages using console-producer outside the cluster not from inside.

Comment: @OneCricketeer 172.17.0.2 is the ip of minikube as i am using kubernetes in minikube on my local system. 30511 is the port that is assigned to kafka pod. Here is an example of kubectl get all
NAME                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                        AGE
service/kafka-cluster        NodePort    10.99.226.255   <none>        9092:30511/TCP                                 20h

Comment: Then you have to set the avertised name to it.

Comment: @ManuelPolacek Can you give me an example what it would be in my case.

Comment: Update your deployment and set the KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=172.17.0.2:30511. As far as i know those are the external names for clients to connect to. If IP and port changed now, of coures you have to update this.

Comment: Or, just use Strimzi, as mentioned https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

A brief explanation of kafka configs:

1. `listeners` - Used by the embedded jetty web server in kafka to bind to. This jetty web server is used to provide REST API that provides the control plane for Kafka Connect workers. The hostname in this setting can be left empty if you want kafka to bind to localhost (it does by calling InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName() java api)
2. `advertised.listeners`: This address is published to zookeeper by every kafka broker. If this setting is not set, then value of listeners will be used here and published to zookeeper. That's the only purpose of this setting for notifying others. Kafka Clients use the 'advertised.listeners' setting published to zookeeper (as /brokers/ids// # endpoints) to talk to Kafka broker. `NOTE: The exception is ZooKeeper-based consumers. These consumers retrieve the broker registration information directly from ZooKeeper and will choose the first listener with PLAINTEXT as the security protocol (the only security protocol they support).` see  (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-103%3A+Separation+of+Internal+and+External+traffic)

In your case, you need to set both `listeners` and `advertised.listeners`.
For external access i.e outside the k8, set `advertised.listerners` address to the node ip or the loadbalancer ip and port to the `nodePort`.
When providing more than one `advtised.listeners` address, make sure the first one in the comma separated url has ip for external access so that it can be populated well in zookeeper for clients to use.

> sample znode output (Clients will use PLAINTEXT://172.28.120.125:30029) which is resolvable outside k8 environment. (Config: advertised.listeners=OUTSIDE://172.28.120.125:30029,INSIDE://:9092)
>
> > [zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 11] get /brokers/ids/0
> > {"features":{},"listener_security_protocol_map":{"OUTSIDE":"PLAINTEXT","INSIDE":"PLAINTEXT"},"endpoints":["OUTSIDE://172.28.120.125:30029","INSIDE://kafka-6877666f69-br7c4:9092"],"jmx_port":-1,"port":30029,"host":"172.28.120.125","version":5,"timestamp":"1638483151305"}

> When advertised.listeners is set to localhost or empty(e.g PLAINTEXT://:9092) the pod's hostname will be advertised hence you will see that error (UnknownHostException). This is how the hostname is advertised in zookeeper. In this case PLAINTEXT://kafka-55d5d99c89-ksr5n:9092 will be advertised which is unresolvable outside k8 environment. (Config: advertised.listeners=INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://172.28.120.125:30029)
>
> > [zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 3] get /brokers/ids/0
> > {"features":{},"listener_security_protocol_map":{"INSIDE":"PLAINTEXT","OUTSIDE":"PLAINTEXT"},"endpoints":["INSIDE://kafka-55d5d99c89-ksr5n:9092","OUTSIDE://172.28.120.125:9094"],"jmx_port":-1,"port":9092,"host":"kafka-55d5d99c89-ksr5n","version":5,"timestamp":"1638517892783"}

Check sample config below.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-service
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    name: kafka
spec:
  selector:
    app: kafka
    id: "0"  
  ports:
  - port: 30029
    targetPort: 30029
    nodePort: 30029
    name: kafka-port
    protocol: TCP 
  type: NodePort     
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: kafka
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    name: kafka
spec:
  replicas: 1 
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
        id: "0"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kafka
        image: wurstmeister/kafka 
        env:
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
          value: OUTSIDE://172.28.120.125:30029,INSIDE://:9092
        - name: KAFKA_LISTENERS
          value: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:30029
        - name: KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP
          value: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
        - name: KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME
          value: INSIDE
        - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
          value: zookeeper:2181
        - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
          value: "0"
      volumes:
      - name: kafka-pv
        persistentVolumeClaim: 
          claimName: my-pvc
```